# Web3js: How do you specify gas limit for transactions?

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, gas-limit

I'm running into some issues with metamask estimating the wrong amount of gas for a specific transaction for my Dapp. It needs around 130k gas to execute, but metamask (around 5% of the time) will set the gas limit to 50k, and I'll get the out of gas revert because of it.

Is there a way for me, in my web3.js code, to tell metamask 'you need 130k gas for this transaction', so i never get the revert?

I try this but metamask ignores it, seemingly.

```
await contract.methods.functionThatReverts(web3.utils.toWei((100000).toString(), 'ether')).send({from: accounts[0], gas:130000})
```

Comment: Please note that there's some confusion in the gas limit parameter: some libraries uses the `gas` label, others use the `gasLimit` label (the same label you can find for blocks).

Have you tried `gasLimit` instead of `gas`?

Comment: @GiuseppeBertone I have tried gasLimit as well yeah, but it didn't work either unfortunately